# Unable to create Google map fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Trying to implement google map API in my android project and getting the warning error that is under my java code

```
GoogleMap gMap;

gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

LatLng Jamaica = new LatLng(18.1155173, -77.2760026);

gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Jamaica, 13));

gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .title("Jamaica")
    .snippet("The greatest country in the world")
    .position(Jamaica));
gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Logcat:

```
03-18 12:45:00.140: W/ActivityThread(10477): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `cmd` and genereate a new "SHA1" key.
2. Browse to https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect `API Console` page.
3. Replace the old "ShA1" with the new "sha1" key.
4. Then replace your new map key.

Your problem solved.  I also had this problem. (I only changed my map key)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

to your manifest under the application tag?

Comment: 03-19 08:58:50.250: I/Choreographer(2443): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.